# iPhone - strange issue with UIScrollView and touches

Tags: iphone, uiscrollview

I have two UIImageView objects inside my view (both 320x480 one above the other). The lower image view is inside a UIScrollView with scrolling and zooming enabled. Now I want to handle touches inside the other image view but it no longer detects any single taps.

I can understand that the UIScrollView handles all the touches which I do on it. But the touches on the image view above the scroll view are also not recognized.

Attached is an image with my view hierarchy. Can someone please tell me why the other image view's touches are also handled by the scrollview when it isn't a subview of scroll view?

And if the scrollview is bent on handling touches, how do I recognize touches on the other image view?

Thanks.
[image]

Comment: I think you'll have to tell us more about what you're trying to do. Why do you have overlapping views in this way? Is there any relation whatsoever between the "other" image view and the scroll view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default UIImageViews have userInteractionEnabled=NO;

Try setting it to YES (either in IB or in code).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, it might be that you need to set the frame size and/or content size of the scroll view properly. [This page](http://www.lyingonthecovers.net/?p=366) has a diagram of what I'm talking about.

Comment: Thanks. probably i wasn't clear, but its difficult to explain. the scrollbars appear fine. The problem is my other imageview (one which is not a subview of scrollview) is not recognizing touches. even they are being handled by the scrollview. Thanks anyways.